# Volley GET Request : End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android

I Have A Problem... 
My Php Code Working by GET Method, When I  GET "ID"  &  GET "Rate" My SQLDatabase Updated and My Output is tree Parameter EncodedJson ( OldRate, YourRate, TotalRate).
After Encode A PHP Output It Seems Correct, BUT in AndroidStudio My GET Request Method Having Problem. The ERROR Content is Like This:

```
01-20 15:04:25.883 3623-3623/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley E/ERROR: Error occurred 
                                                                        com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:73)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:121)
                                                                         Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
                                                                            at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
                                                                            at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
                                                                            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                            at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.parseNetworkResponse(JsonObjectRequest.java:68)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:121)
```

It's My PHP Code:

```
<?php
require_once 'include\config.php';
// connect to database
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

//GETS
if(isset ($_GET['ID']) && isset($_GET['Rating'])){
$ID = $_GET['ID'];  
$MyRate = $_GET['Rating'];  }
else{return;}


//CountVote
$sql1="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `Counter`= `Counter`+1 WHERE `ID`=$ID";
$sql2= "SELECT `Counter` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";
if($con->query($sql1) === TRUE ){
    //echo "Item updated successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
}
if ($result = $con->query($sql2)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $COUNTVote=$row["Counter"];
    //echo "<br>".$row["Counter"]."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}


//PASTVote
if(`Counter`<1){
$sql3="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `PastRate`= (`PastRate`+$MyRate)/2 WHERE `ID`=$ID";}
else{$sql3="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `PastRate`= 0 WHERE `ID`=$ID";}
$sql4= "SELECT `PastRate` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";
if($con->query($sql3) === TRUE ){
    //echo "Item updated successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
}
if ($result = $con->query($sql4)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $PASTVote=$row["PastRate"];
    //echo "<br>".$row["PastRate"]."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}  

//YOURVote
$sql5 = "UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `YourRate`='$MyRate' WHERE `ID`=$ID";
$sql6="SELECT `YourRate` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";
if($con->query($sql5) === TRUE){
    //echo "Item updated successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
}
if ($result = $con->query($sql6)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $YOURVote=$row["YourRate"];
    //echo "<br>".$YOURVote['YourRate']."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}  

//AVVote
if(`Counter`<1 ){
$sql7="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET `Rating`=($MyRate + (`Counter`-1)*`PastRate`)/`Counter`  WHERE ID=$ID";}
else{$sql7="UPDATE `civilarticle` SET  `Rating`= $MyRate WHERE `ID`=$ID";}
$sql8= "SELECT `Rating` FROM `civilarticle` WHERE `ID`=$ID";

if($con->query($sql7) === TRUE){
    //echo "Item inserted successfully"."<br>";
} else{
    echo "Error : " . $con->error ;
} 
if ($result = $con->query($sql8)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $AVVote=$row["Rating"];
    //echo "<br>".$row["Rating"]."<br>"."*****"."<br>";
}}
```

In the Following in PHP Code, I Have Encode Them:

```
$arr=array("OldRate"=>$PASTVote,"YourRate"=>$YOURVote,"TotalRate"=>$AVVote,"CountVote"=>$COUNTVote);
json_encode($arr);
```

And My JavaClass:

```
int ID=1; //put extra give me this value
public float Rate;
Button btn_submit,btn_detail;
RatingBar ratingbar;


String url= "mylink/android_login_api/rating.php";
TextView pastrate,yourrate,totalrate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    txtTiltle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMain);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    ///
    btn_detail= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    pastrate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    yourrate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    totalrate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.t3);
    ////

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras!=null){
        if(extras.containsKey("Title")){
            title = extras.getString("Title");
            txtTiltle.setText(title);
        }
    }

    ///my code for rating
    btn_submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Rate = ratingbar.getRating();
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,""+ratingbar.getRating(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(Rate!=-1){
                btn_submit.setEnabled(false);


            }

        }

    });



    btn_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            CustomRequest CustomRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                pastrate.setText(response.getString("OldRate"));
                                yourrate.setText(response.getString("YourRate"));
                                totalrate.setText( response.getString("TotalRate"));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                             Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,response+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", volleyError);
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
            })
            {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("ID", String.valueOf(ID));
                        params.put("Rating",String.valueOf(Rate));
                        return params;
                    }
            };

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(CustomRequest);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Please HELP ME... Thank YOU...

Comment: cross check your url i think it's now working.

Comment: @DileepPatel Thanks for Your Comment, But It Works... 
My Android Code Have A Problem, I Think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in PHP you are sending as Array and on android client side you are reading as object.  If you would like to receive in Json object in android client then see the below example

```
<?php
$myObj->name = "John";
$myObj->age = 30;
$myObj->city = "New York";

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

The output will look like

```
{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}
```

The above output  in proper JSON object format.

If you would like receive as Json array then you should send as Json array and read as JSON array on client side.

I hope this will help

Please refer below to understand how the Json should be formed in PHP side.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: Sorry, My OutPut, In this case, is an object :
{
"OldRate": "3.99997",
"YourRate": "4",
"TotalRate": "3.99997",
"CountVote": "17"
}

Are You Sure My PHP code Having Problem?
ThankYou Soo much

Comment: are you sure PHP server getting the hit? As url doesn't contain host name

Comment: Yes, I See output after search in my browser .... this is my output:
 { "OldRate": "3.99997", "YourRate": "4", "TotalRate": "3.99997", "CountVote": "17" }

Comment: When I Change the url in my java class to 
"https://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/rating.php?"+"ID="+ID+"&"+"Rating="+Rate

and run this, the counter in my SQL database work but other parameters not working...

Comment: is this is what you are sending https://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/rating.php?" "ID=" ID "&" "Rating="Rate   Did u cross checked the url or print the final url you are requesting. And use the decoder to see are your sending the params properly. use this https://www.url-encode-decode.com

Comment: in java at the first url be  "192.168.1.103/android_login_api/rating.php"; 
but when change this to 192.168.1.103/android_login_api/rating.php?"+"ID="+ID+"&"+"Rating="+Rate my counter worked

Comment: Yes, Yes ... When I get a toast show to me,
https://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/rating.php?ID=1&Rating=0.0 
What is its meaning!!??